# What is proxy and stub in web-services?

Tags: web-services, proxy, stub

As per definition from https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/203516-Whats-a-proxy-stub

> Proxy is the piece of code that doesn't perform any functions of its
>   own, but instead is responsible for calling the real code.

But I am not clear about stub,
What is stub, and what it does?
What is the difference between two?

Comment: A proxy is a placeholder, or representative for something real. A stub is usually some code you write just to help you out with unit testing. Where did you get the quote from because context is important in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're talking RPC<sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)]</sup> systems in web services( SOAP<sup>[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)]</sup>, REST<sup>[[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)]</sup> etc)

> What is stub?

A stub for a remote object acts as a client's proxy (local representative) for the remote object.

> what it does?

It is responsible for carrying out the method call on the remote object which is  invoked by a caller to a method.